# Gradle cannot find core project with libGDX in iOS module

Tags: android, ios, gradle, libgdx

I write a libGDX game sometime ago that I released only for Android. Now, I'd like to release it for iOS too so I have retaken the development. I have already updated all the dependencies and stuff to the most up-to-date gradle plugin and things like that, and to libGDX-1.9.10. I had to deal with a number of issues to get everything working together again, but it finally did.

Now, following advise from an article in Medium and as a first step to port my game to iOS, and as my own project didn't have a ios module, I have created a new project with the last gdx-setup.jar available. After copying the ios module and modifying its gradle file, this is what I have in the ios/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "robovm"

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

ext {
    mainClassName = "com.marzoa.game.IOSLauncher"
}

launchIPhoneSimulator.dependsOn build
launchIPadSimulator.dependsOn build
launchIOSDevice.dependsOn build
createIPA.dependsOn build

robovm {
    archs = "thumbv7:arm64"
}

dependencies {
    api project(':core')
    api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:2.3.11"
    api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:2.3.11"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:1.9.10"
    api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-ios"
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error when trying to build:

> Failed to resolve: project::core Affected Modules:
> LuckiestWheelGDX.ios

Weird thing is that the core project is definitely there. Not only that, but every other module depends on that one too, and these build without problems. For example, the dependencies for the android module begin like this:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':core')
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:1.9.10"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-x86"
```

As you see, the first dependecy is the same that with ios, which works perfectly well from android/build.gradle but not for ios/build.gradle.

So, what am I missing here?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4):

So the problem was pretty stupid, but I'll leave it here for the record, it may be useful for someone else.

That error message is miss-leading and hiding the real issue. I run the build again with the gradle-wrapper in a terminal and found out this:

- Incompatible attribute:
  - Required org.gradle.jvm.version '7' and found incompatible value '8'.

The issue is that my project is using Java 8 since a while ago, but the module generated by gdx-setup defaults to Java 7, so I just had to replace this:

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
```

with this:

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
```

In the build.gradle file of the ios module, and now it's building as expected.